# how does an armature influence a mesh in detail?

Tags: python, armature, bones

I write a python exporter for meshes and other related data.
I also want to export the aramture and use these data in an own program.
For an armature i can export attributes bones data like:

- matrix
- head
- location
- ...

I export the mesh along with vertex groups and weights, all that is working.

What i'd like to know is how the vertices in the vertex groups are influenced by the armature / the bones.

Are their coordinates just multiplied by the matrices (influence by weight)?

Some detail about the used algorithm would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Torsten